# Python:Subprocess Popen exits immediately for Large file

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

**Requirement**: Execute the script to edit the file

**Issue:** For big file, it doesn't wait for the entire process to be completed and immediately gets printed "Transform script successful", whereas the file was not updated. If it is small file it gets executed fine

How can I make sure it waits until the entire process is completed ??

**Part Code**

```
with NamedTemporaryFile("wb") as f_source, NamedTemporaryFile("wb") as f_dest:
            source_s3_key_object.download_fileobj(Fileobj=f_source)
            f_source.flush()

            if self.transform_script is not None:
                process = subprocess.Popen(
                    [self.transform_script, f_source.name, f_dest.name],
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                    close_fds=True
                )

                self.log.info("Output:")
                for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
                    self.log.info(line.decode(self.output_encoding).rstrip())

                process.wait()

                if process.returncode > 0:
                    raise AirflowException(
                        "Transform script failed: {0}".format(process.returncode)
                    )
                else:
                    self.log.info(
                        "Transform script successful. Output temporarily located at %s",
                        f_dest.name
                    )
```

**Python Script**

**Log for small file:**

```
[2020-07-07 20:35:37,892] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:115} INFO - Downloading source S3 file s3://path/incoming.2020-07-07.txt
[2020-07-07 20:35:41,981] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:124} INFO - Dumping S3 file s3://path/incoming.2020-07-07.txt contents to local file /tmp/tmp3v_6i1go
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,115] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:145} INFO - Output:
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,293] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - Starting data cleaning...
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,293] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:147} INFO - Completed data cleaning!
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,298] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:158} INFO - Transform script successful. Output temporarily located at /tmp/tmp8uo9t2lk
[2020-07-07 20:35:42,298] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:161} INFO - Uploading transformed file to S3
[2020-07-07 20:35:43,983] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:168} INFO - Upload successful
```

**For big file log :**

```
[2020-07-07 20:25:37,892] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:115} INFO - Downloading source S3 file s3://path/incoming.2020-07-07.txt
[2020-07-07 20:25:52,027] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:124} INFO - Dumping S3 file s3://path/incoming.2020-07-07.txt contents to local file /tmp/tmpgayy9hg9
[2020-07-07 20:26:26,256] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:145} INFO - Output:
[2020-07-07 20:26:29,137] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:158} INFO - Transform script successful. Output temporarily located at /tmp/tmpui1i28r6
[2020-07-07 20:26:29,137] {s3_file_transform_operator.py:161} INFO - Uploading transformed file to S3
```

transform_script.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
from contextlib import closing
import mmap
import sys
import logging
import os
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
"""
Read the last line of the file and remove the double quotes and extra delimiters
and write back to the file.
"""
input = sys.argv[1]
output = sys.argv[2]

def clnup(input, output):
    try:
        with open(input, 'r+b') as myfile:
            with closing(mmap.mmap(myfile.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)) as mm:
                start_of_line = mm.rfind(b'\n', 0, len(mm) - 1) + 1
                line = mm[start_of_line:].rstrip(b'\r\n')
                last_line = line.decode('utf-8').replace("\"", "")
                last_line = re.sub('[|]*$', '', last_line).encode('utf-8')
            myfile.seek(start_of_line)  # Move to where old line began
            myfile.write(last_line)  # Overwrite existing line with new line
            myfile.truncate()
        with open(input, 'r+b') as myfile:
            f = open("temp.txt", "w+b")
            f.write(myfile.read())
        with open("temp.txt", 'r+b') as myfile:
            f = open(output, "w+b")
            f.write(myfile.read())
        os.remove("temp.txt")
    except Exception as ex:
            logger.error(f'Error in updating the file. Message: {ex}')
            raise

print("Starting data cleaning...")
clnup(input, output)
print("Completed data cleaning!")
```

Comment: It's too much code to read, could you narrow it down to a minimal example? Probably you will also resolve the issue while doing so.

Comment: I tried all means, nothing helped me :(